# How to change the tag of a draft?

Tags: support, documentation

I've spent a fair amount of time writing a document on Stack Overflow's documentation beta. It has been rejected by two reviewers for being in the wrong tag. I've put it in the XAML tag, and they're saying it should be in the WPF tag.

I can't work out how to change the tag, and I don't want to have to create it all again from scratch just because a tag is wrong. Can anyone please help?

(Is it possible for the document to have two tags?)

Comment: Are you asking about changing the tag an existing topic is in or changing the tag after you started drafting a whole new topic?

Comment: Take the draft, edit it, copy the content, go to WPF, create a new example, paste the content.

Comment: To JonEricson, I created a new draft topic. @MikeMcCaughan: Thanks, that worked. I thought I would lose my pictures and the formatting; but it works. If you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.     Now I have my fingers crossed that it doesn't get rejected from WPF with the suggestion it should be in XAML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the tag once you've started a draft. The easiest way of doing this is to open the draft and copy the content in edit mode. Create a new example (or topic, or whatever) and paste the code into the new example. That should preserve all of the formatting and pictures, as it will be encoded in the Markdown.

Answer (score -3):

Tags are actually just your favorite tags. To "edit" them, just add/remove tags from your favorites and (after you blame caching) it would change.

Comment: A reasonable guess, but no. Favorite (or ignored) tags have nothing to do with how [Documentation](//stackoverflow.com/documentation) is organized.